# Would a composite index help the following query?

Tags: mysql

Is there a way to craft a composite index to speed up the below query?

```
DELETE n1 

    FROM 
        table n1, table n2 

    WHERE 
            n1.id < n2.id 
        AND 
            n1.col1 = n2.col1 
        AND 
            n1.col2 = n2.col2 
        AND 
            n1.col3 = n2.col3
```

Comment: What index are you proposing here? `col1,col2,col3` would be a good place to start.

Comment: why not just use a JOIN? and yes you should put a composite index on the three columns

Answer (score 0):

After a ton of research, it seems that this index is the way to go -

`ALTER IGNORE TABLE table ADD UNIQUE INDEX dupefilter (col1, col2, col3 )`

Now that original query is unnecessary.  If anyone sees a potential issue with this, please comment back.  I'm surprised that unique index is not recommended more often.